# Program to use a second PC as second monitor

Tags: windows, linux, remote-access, display

I've seen that application but I forgot to note its name down, and now I can't find it:

You to place e.g. your laptop next to your desktop PC's monitor, you start the application in question on both and the laptop's screen becomes a second monitor to your desktop PC.

It's similar in a manner to VNC, TeamViewer and Remote Desktop, but while they can act as a second monitor in 'Clone' mode, this one simulates 'expand/span' mode - the native desktop of one PC spans screens of both computers.

IIRC the application allowed to mix Windows and Linux PCs freely (use Windows PC as host to display extended Linux screen, and vice versa, get Linux machine to display a part of Windows desktop).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It hasn't been updated in a while, and dosen't work with aero(and I suspect dwm composited desktops in general, so it won't work with 8), but that sounds a lot like [zonescreen](http://www.zoneos.com/zonescreen.htm). Another alternative may be [maxivista](http://www.maxivista.com/).

I do note neither of these lets you use a linux system as a host, though I suspect that you may be able to jerryrig one with clever abuse of X.

Comment: I'm not accepting yet because I believe there was a different solution, more up-to-date than zonescreen and free (unlike maxvista), but these are very nice suggestions. If nothing better pops up, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: I'd be quite happy if someone finds something better, since I have a few old spare laptops I wouldn't mind repurposing this way ;)

Answer (score 1):

In Linux (or probably Mac or some other Unix) you can use x2x https://help.ubuntu.com/community/X2xHowto

Comment: Does it provide the 'dual screen/expand' capability? All I read about is 'remote control'

Answer (score 0):

[AirParrot 2](http://www.airsquirrels.com/airparrot/) with combination with its "receiver" application [Reflector 2](http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/) allows for this functionality. AirParrot is available for Windows, MacOS, ChromeOS; Reflector on top of these additionally supports iOS and Android devices.

They are both paid applications. Demo displaying a watermark is available, so they can be tried for free, but not really usable.

[example video](https://youtu.be/XX9KP0EWIRw?t=1m59s)