# Software to extend your monitor on another Windows PC

Tags: windows, open-source, remote-desktop, display, screen-sharing

I have two Windows PCs (one laptop and one desktop) and I would like to use the laptop screen as an extension.

Open source is a big plus, but not a must.

This software Synergy does not put the display/ extend the display to the other screen, but rather lets you control two separate systems, which is not exactly what I want. It should work in a local network (LAN and WiFi). Veyon does not have the ability to extend the display as far as I know.

Any idea of such software?

This [Program to use a second PC as second monitor](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/609/program-to-use-a-second-pc-as-second-monitor) apparently has outdated answers..

Comment: apparently you can project but it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

There's a fork of Synergy called [Barrier](https://github.com/debauchee/barrier), I didn't try it myself although. I was a user of Synergy many years ago, I just found it as an alternative a long time ago on [Alternativeto](https://alternativeto.net/software/synergy/) site

The original Synergy is a **virtual KVM switch**, letting you share a keyboard and mouse between two PCs, each with its own monitor. Since Barrier is a fork of an older release of Synergy I'm quite confident it has the same features - plus anything that's been updated and corrected over time.

What is interesting about it is that you still have two (or more) separate computers (running even different OSes, where needed), but as you move the mouse *beyond* a screen border that you choose, you are *entering* the screen of another machine, starting interacting with it.

The connection is made with a running client/server application, through the local network connection on which the computers reside.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Miracast - it's integrated into Windows 10 already. You do apparently need to put both devices (if they're both running Windows)  into private network mode instead of public and then start the miracast program integrated into Windows on one machine and then click Windows+K to attach from the other machine.